# Como alterar o imagem do + da treeview c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Quero alterar o + da **treeview**, segue o exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima da pra ver o que o + fico desproporcional ao nome, gostaria de alterar o tamanho e juntamente o design do +, substituindo pela seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]